# Folder Comparisons Via Command Line

Tags: windows, cmd, comparison, directory

I want to compare two folders on Windows (Vista, XP) which have a large number of huge files, which I need to compare. If I use Beyond Compare or such tool to compare the folders, it is taking a lot of time if I do it manually. I need to add that folder comparison to batch file.

So on Windows (XP, Vista), is there any command (built-in) or any 3rd party tool/utility (commercial or freeware - either) to compare two folders using the command line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is the built in command `COMP` that you could use. It depends a little bit on what you actually want to compare.

> Compares the contents of two files or
>   sets of files.
>
> COMP [data1] [data2] [/D] [/A] [/L]
>   [/N=number] [/C]
>
> data1     Specifies location and
>   name(s) of first file(s) to compare.
>
> data2     Specifies location and
>   name(s) of second files to compare.
>
> /D        Displays differences in
>   decimal format.
>
> /A        Displays
>   differences in ASCII characters.
>
> /L 
>   Displays line numbers for differences.
>
> /N=number Compares only the first
>   specified number of lines in each
>   file.
>
> /C        Disregards case of
>   ASCII letters when comparing files.
>
> To compare sets of files, use wildcards in data1 and data2 parameters.

Use a syntax like `COMP c:\folder1 c:\folder2` to compare all files in `folder1` with the content of `folder2`. If you need to recurse into the subdirectories, you need to use a batch script using a `FOR` loop and the `PUSHD` and `POPD` command.

Just leave a comment, if you need help with that.

Comment: how to use this `COMP` for recursively with two folder. I tried like this `COMP C:\folder1\* C:\folder2\*` but this does not return all file.

Answer (score 15):

```
>diff -r Folder_A Folder_B
```

You may find GNU diffutils compiled for windows at [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019897/4304516 for useful options you can add to this command.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)'s versions of the Unix command line tools:

```
diff -r dir1 dir2
```

I've also used [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) in the past.  Both have a few gotchas, but are "close enough."  For visual diffs, I like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

```
forfiles /P %folder1Path% /S /C "cmd /c comp /a @path %folder2Path%\@file"
```

Will work, but I can't remove the prompt question after the first comparison is made.

Comment: wont work bc @file wont go to the subdir of the folder1

Answer (score 0):

Basing on answer of Martin Tournoij I'v written next (and it working well):

```
del a.txt
forfiles /P %1 /M *.c* /S /C "cmd /c comp /a @path @file /M" >> a.txt
forfiles /P %1 /M *.h /S /C "cmd /c comp /a @path @file /M" >> a.txt
forfiles /P %1 /M *.s /S /C "cmd /c comp /a @path @file /M" >> a.txt
```

It looks in subdirectories and don't ask any quiestions...

Answer (score -2):

My two directories have the same structure, just a few version changes to the files.  Furthermore, my directory was just a folder of python files.  So i got away with...

```
$ cat dir1/*.py > file1.txt 
$ cat dir2/*.py > file2.txt
$ diff file1 file2
```

Comment: 1) This is a Windows question, 2) You can use `diff -r`, no need for `cat`.