# How to diff files with same name from two different folders?

Tags: svn, sed, awk

I see this, but it does NOT quite give me what I need. [Diff files present in two different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019857/diff-files-present-in-two-different-directories)

I want to diff ALL the pom.xml files, but from two different directory trees in a multi-module struncture. So I have

dir1/pom.xml
dir1/module1/pom.xml
dir1/module1/project1/pom.xml
dir1/module2/pom.xml
etc...

dir2/pom.xml
dir2/module1/pom.xml
dir2/module1/project1/pom.xml
dir2/module2/pom.xml
etc...

I want to diff ALL the pom.xml files, and ONLY the pom.xml files, between dir1 and dir2. I'm currently using SVN, so either a sed or svn-specific command may be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the same file names exist in both directories:

```
find dir1 -name pom.xml |
while IFS= read -r file1
do
    file2="${file1//dir1/dir2}"
    diff "$file1" "$file2"
done
```

If not, just add a test for the file existing and a second loop going the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder structure is the same, maybe you could be running:

```
cd dir1
find . -name pom.xml -exec diff {} ../dir2/{} \;
```

I can't test it right now...