# Recursively compare specific files in different directories

Tags: bash, unix, compare, diff

Similar posts here:

[Diff files present in two different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2019857/4552125)

and here:

https://superuser.com/q/602877/520666

But not quite what I'm looking for.

I have 2 directories (containing subdirectories and different file types -- binary, images, html, etc.).

I want to be able to recursively compares files with specific extensions (e.g. .html, .strings, etc.) between the two directories -- they may or may not exist in either (sub)directory.

How can I accomplish this?  Diff only seems to support exclusions, and I'm not sure how I can leverage Find for this.

Advice?

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude all unwanted fileendings with find:

(this version only matches against file endings)

```
diff -r -x `find . -type f -name '*.*' | sed 's|.*\.|.*\.|' | sort -u | grep -v YOURFILETYPE |  paste -sd "|"` ...rest of diff command
```

Or you generate the list of excluded files upfront and pass it to the diff:

(this version also matches against filenames and every other regex you specify in include.file)

```
find /dirA -type f | grep -v YOURFILEENDING > exclude.list
find /dirB -type f | grep -v YOURFILEENDING >> exclude.list
diff -X exclude.list -r /dirA /dirB
```

If you chain these commands via `&&` you'll get a handy oneliner ;)

---

**WITH INCLUDE FILE**

If you want to use an include file, you can use this Method:

1. You specify the include file
2. grep matches against all files in the folders and turns your includefile into an exclude file for diff (diff only takes exclude files)

Here is an example:

Complicated inline version:

(this version only matches against file endings)

```
diff -r -x `find . -type f -name '*.*' | sed 's|.*\.|.*\.|' sort -u | grep -v -f include.file |  paste -sd "|"` /dirA /dirB
```

Slightly longer simpler version:

(this version also matches against filenames and every other regex you specify in include.file)

```
find /dirA -type f | grep -v -f include.file > exclude.list
find /dirB -type f | grep -v -f include.file >> exclude.list
diff -X exclude.list -r /dirA /dirB
```

with each line in include.file being a grep regex/expression:

```
log
txt
fileending3
whateverfileendingyoulilke
fullfilename.txt
someotherregex.*
```

---

**NOTE**

I did not run these because I'm nowhere near a computer.
I hope I got all syntax correct.

Comment: I like this idea, but how could I use an inverted method and only diff against an "include.list" ?

Comment: @vmoralito I've just updated my post and came up with a method to dynamically generate an exclude file out of an include file, because diff will only take exclude file. But using the way above, you can use your include file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is to compare the whole directories:

```
diff -r /path/the/first /path/the/second
```

It will show which files are only in one of the directories, which files differ in a binary fashion, and the full diff for any textual files in both directories.

You can loop over a set of *relative paths* by simply reading a file with a path per line thusly:

```
while IFS= read -u 9 relative_path
do
    diff "/path/the/first/%{relative_path}" "/path/the/second/%{relative_path}"
done 9< relative_paths.txt
```

Doing this for a specific set of *extensions* is similarly easy:

```
shopt -s globstar
while IFS= read -u 9 extension    do
    diff "/path/the/first/"**/*."${extension}" "/path/the/second/"**/*."${extension}"
done 9< extensions.txt
```

Comment: This was already covered in the posts referenced in the question. Unfortunately, there are over 2600+ files in each 'parent' directory, and a LOT of them will contain changes that I don't care about. I'm only interested in the changes for the specific files I need to worry about. I'll keep poking around.