# linux diff on folder and file structure

Tags: linux, bash, compare, diff

I know how to do a `diff` on file *contents* (both with `diff` and `git diff`), but how do I do a "diff" on two folders both containing files and subfolders, to see files that are missing or exclusively present in one but not the other - without seeing any of the content differences?

An absolute bonus would be the ability to see if files are positionally present in both but have a different size in bytes - but the first would be sufficient for almost all I need.

Comment: I didn't find a pure `diff` solution but you can use diff to compare two lists of files: `diff <(find DIR1 -printf '%P\n' | sort) <(find DIR2 -printf '%P\n' | sort)`...
Actually, I'll just write this answer in the other question.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330387/3052438