# How to compare two folders without opening beyond compare window from CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, beyondcompare4

I want to compare two folders and all I have is directory path of two folders. How to use Beyond Compare 4 CLI commands to compare them without actually opening the window. I have been using the below command but it opens up the window every time.

```
C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe C:\BeyondC\Folder C:\BeyondC\NoFolder /fv=Folder Compare /silent
```

How to compare folders without actually opening BeyondCompare window ?

Comment: I found [this post](https://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?3094-Using-BC-with-Command-line-scripting). Have you tried?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I found [the answer about `comp`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732838/folder-comparisons-via-command-line) too. Is it not your option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Beyond Compare script to compare two folders and output comparison results to a file.

Script:

```
criteria timestamp size
load c:\folder1 c:\folder2
expand all
folder-report layout:side-by-side output-to:c:\report.txt
```

To run the script, pass it as a command line argument with @ in front of the name. The @ character makes Beyond Compare run a file as a script rather than load it for interactive comparison.

```
bcompare.exe /silent @c:\script.txt
```

See the **Using Beyond Compare > Scripts** and **Scripting Reference** topics in Beyond Compare 4's help file for more on scripting.